# Django: select status, count(status) from table group_by status;

Tags: django, django-orm

I know that there is no `group_by` in Django for some reason. However, I need to get the number of items in each of the possible statuses. It can be done with a very simple query:

```sql
select status, count(status) from table group_by status;
```

At the same time, in our project we try to do as much as possible in Django ORM, and so far have never used raw SQL anywhere except in some migrations.

Is there a way to do this in Django ORM without getting duplicates?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this(with [**`annotation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/#topics-db-aggregation)):

```
from django.db.models import Count    
YourModel.objects.values('status').annotate(status_count=Count('status'))
```

Comment: The problem is that i get a status_count for each row in the db, not for each distinct status. Say, if I do YourModel.objects.values('status').annotate(status_count=Count('status')).values_list('status', 'status_count'), i get: [(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (4, 1)]

Comment: I tested in Django 1.11(pretty old one) with MySQL, and I get something like this: `<QuerySet [{'status': 1, 'count': 6}, {'status': 2, 'count': 4}, {'status': 4, 'count': 4}]>`

Comment: I am using Django 3.0 and PostgreSQL. I have double checked, my code is exactly like yours.

Comment: Also, are you sure you are not adding other values like, for example if you pass multiple parameters through `values(...)` then it won't work. If your code is exactly like mine, then it should work.

Comment: I looked at the query it was generating. Turns out, there was an additional `group_by` clause there. Removing ordering with `.order_by()` helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) to group your queryset.

```
from django.db.models import Count
MyModel.objects.values('status').annotate(num=Count('status'))
```

will return `<QuerySet [{'status': 1, 'num': 4}, {'status': 2, 'num': 12}...]>`

Note: if you have any ordering on your model or on your default manager, you'll have to remove that first by adding `order_by()`.

Comment: I get a `num` for each row in the db: `[{'status': 1, 'num': 1}, {'status': 1, 'num': 1}, {'status': 1, 'num': 1}, {'status': 1, 'num': 1}, {'status': 1, 'num': 1}, {'status': 1, 'num': 1}, {'status': 1, 'num': 1}, {'status': 4, 'num': 1}]`

Comment: This works for me both in Django 2.2 and 3.0 so there's something else in your code than just what we show here. Do you override the default manager (`objects`)? Is there a default ordering?

Comment: I looked at the query it was generating. Turns out, there was an additional group_by clause there. Removing ordering with .order_by() helped.